# Don't pass custom variable if not entered

Tags: php, mysql

I am completely brand new to mysql and php. I'm working on a project which has a lot of user input for querying the database.

I am having trouble having multiple user options to query a database.

```
     <form action="QUERYFORM1.php" method="get">

  <div><label for="Value1">Enter Value1
  <input type="text" name="Value1" id="Value1"/>
  </label>  
</div>

   <div><label for="Value2">Enter Value2
  <input type="text" name="Value2" id="Value2"/>
  </label>  

     <div><input type="submit" value="Go"/></div>

    </form>
```

Above is the user input form, it works if you enter two values but if you only enter one, the query comes back blank because of the query then asking for a blank value.

Is it possible to not pass the variable to the next page if it isn't entered?

Here are some pieces of code from the php file that the form initiates

```
    $Value1 = $_GET['Value1'];
    $Value2 = $_GET['Value2']; 


$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM trackdata WHERE Value1='$Value1' AND Value2='$Value2'"); 
if (!$result)  
{  

  $error = 'Error fetching data: ' . mysqli_error($link);  

  include 'error.html.php';  

  exit();  

}  


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['Value1'] . " " . $row['Value2'];
}
```

Is there a php function that I can use so that if the Value1 is blank, it would still query the database only using value2?

Hope this makes sense and sorry if this is such a simple question, I have searched and searched for answers online and cant find nothing.

Thanks

Comment: This would work perfectly,
if($Value1=""){
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM trackdata WHERE Value2='$Value2'");
} else {
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM trackdata WHERE Value1='$Value1' AND Value2='$Value2'");
}

But if there is more than lets say I had 5 values there that were able to be requested by the user, and only 3 were filled out, how would I be able to tackle it?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have five values

```
$_GET['Value1'] ..... $_GET['Value5']

$query = "";

foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{
  if(!empty($value))
  {
    if(empty($query))
    {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM trackdata WHERE ".$key."=".$value;
    }
    else
    {
      $query .= " AND ".$key."=".$value;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Hi, it doesnt seem to be working, but this is due to a lack of knowledge on my side, your code will work but I cant get it to work in my script, I must be doing something wrong. This is a longshot but would you be able to actually write that out in a full script I would need for the query to run? I think the problem is with my $result and mysqli_fetch_array.

Comment: well you can debug step by step, use print_r($_GET) to see the sytax of the data coming, 2ndly check your query run on phpadmin or any other gui you using. then write the code to making a dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's pretty straightforward: you can use an "if" statement.
If Value 1 is blank, then query using only Value 2, else query using both values.

```
if($Value1=""){
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM trackdata WHERE Value2='$Value2'");
} else {
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM trackdata WHERE Value1='$Value1' AND Value2='$Value2'");
}
```

EDIT: Okay, this one is a bit trickier (I'm especially worried about all the concatenations). The idea is:

1-We store the values in an array

2-We scan the array until we find a non-blank value

3-If we find a non-blank value, we add a WHERE clause and scan the array from this value to the end, looking for other non-blank values

4-Whenever we find a new non-blank value, we add it to the WHERE clause

Try it out:

```
$Value1=$_GET['Value1'];
$Value2=$_GET['Value2'];
...
$ValueN=$_GET['ValueN'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM trackdata";

$values = array(1 => $Value1, $Value2... , $ValueN);

for($i = 1; $i < count($values)+1; $i++){

   if($values[$i] != ""){

      $query = $query." WHERE Value".$i."='$Value".$i."'"; //begin the WHERE clause with the first non-blank value

      //add all other non-blank values to the WHERE clause
      //to do that, we scan the array from the first non-blank value to the end
      for($j = $i+1; $j < count($values)+1; $j++){

         if($values[$j] != ""){

            $query = $query." AND Value".$j."='$Value".$j."'";

         }

      }

   break;//we break the first for loop, so that it doesn't add undesired WHERE clauses

   }

}

$query = $query.";"; //for good practice, then the query should be good to go!
```

This of course supposes that all your variables are named "ValueX", and that the indices are continuous (i.e. if you have Value1 and Value3, you must have Value2 in between, or it won't work).

Comment: This would work perfectly,

But if there is more than lets say I had 5 values there that were able to be requested by the user, and only 3 were filled out, how would I be able to tackle it?

Comment: @DannyEng14 Indeed, I didn't think of that... I have an idea to get around this, I'll update my post.

Comment: Hi, it doesnt seem to be working, but this is due to a lack of knowledge on my side, your code will work but I cant get it to work in my script, I must be doing something wrong. This is a longshot but would you be able to actually write that out in a full script I would need for the query to run? I think the problem is with my $result and mysqli_fetch_array.

Comment: @DannyEng14 Did you allocate the ValueX variables before storing them in the array? Anyway, I suggest you focus on Robert Loxy's solution above. It's the same principle, but with shorter (and more aesthetical) code. Besides, I realize that my code makes you store variables in an array, which is useless since they are already stored in one ($GET).

Comment: @DannyEng14 Okay, nevermind, but please mention the people you're answering to with an @. This is weird, your comments seem to be posted on multiple answers at once.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this:

```
"SELECT * FROM trackdata WHERE Value1='$Value1'" . ($Value2 ? " AND Value2='$Value2'" : '')
```

?

Comment: Hi just tried this and it gave me a php error when trying to run ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "OR" keyword instead of "AND" in Database query.
So if $value1 is not set $value2 will be checked.

I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

you may split the query to put your logic

eg:

```
   <?php
    $Value1 ='';
    $Value2 = '13';
    if($Value1 || $Value2){ 
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM trackdata WHERE';

         if($Value1 && $Value2){
            $query.= "`Value1`=".$Value1." AND `Value2`=".$Value2;
         }
         elseif(!$Value1){
            $query.= " `Value2`=".$Value2;
         }
        elseif(!$Value2){
            $query.= " `Value1`=".$Value1;
         }
         $query.=';';
         echo $query;
     }
     else{
        echo 'invalid';
     }
```

Comment: Cant seem to get this working either mate (Due to my lack of understanding of PHP), any chance you could put it in a working script that includes the $result bit and mysqli_fetch_array ? Thanks